# Flask returns 405 Method Not Allowed even though POST is specified

Tags: python, flask

I'm getting a 405 Method Not Allowed error when uploading to my `upload_file` route. I've specified that the route accepts the GET and POST methods, so I'm not sure why it's not working.

```py
@app.route('/upload', methods=["GET, POST"])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template("home.html")
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.file:
            return render_template("home.html")

        file = request.files['file']

        if file.filename == '':
            return render_template("home.html")

        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            converted_file = convert(file)
            return render_template("home.html", converted_file=converted_file, img_src=UPLOAD_FOLDER+filename)
```

```html
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload" >
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=["GET, POST"])
```

should be:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=["GET", "POST"])
```

You were giving a list with one string "GET, POST" instead of a list with two strings: "GET" & "POST".

PS:
As described here: [Do not use run() in production.](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.route)

> Do not use run() in a production setting. It is not intended to meet security and performance requirements for a production server. Instead, see Deployment Options for WSGI server recommendations.

Please read [Deployment Options](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/)

Comment: What a silly mistake! Thanks. I will try this out. Also, from the described methods for deployment, which one is the easiest to configure? And if I want to make a change to the server, is pushing the new file the only way, or..?

Comment: It depends on your need. Heroku and PythonAnywhere seem the simpler. But if you need something more resilient and you know what you are doing, AWS, Azure, GCP are better, but they require more skills.